# Building Pandas Frame from Multiple Counters

Tags: python, pandas

I have dictionary of counters. The counters all have the same 'key' but they have different values (i.e different counts). How can I efficiently  convert all these counters into pandas data frame such that each row of the data-frame represents a key and each column represents a counter, the cells contain the count value for that key?

Note: Each counter is associated with an id,  which I would like to keep as the column label

Example:

```
l = {'Name' : Counter({'a': 10, 'b':20})}, {'Name2' : Counter({'a':100, 'b':200})}
```

How do I get:

```
    Name    Name2
a  10       100
b  20       200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using this approach:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

l = {'Name' : Counter({'a': 10, 'b':20})}, {'Name2' : Counter({'a':100, 'b':200})}

columns, data = zip(*[(key, value) for elem in l for key, value in elem.items()])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(data)).T.set_axis(columns, axis=1, inplace=False)

print(df)
#    Name  Name2
# a    10    100
# b    20    200
```